# jquery return ajax success to input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with ajax success loading to input type number. when i change the input type to text it works. but when i change the input type to number it was not loading.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Enter Student Roll Number</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" maxlength="10" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Attended</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="attend" id="attend" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Conducted</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="conduct" id="conduct" disabled/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#roll').change(function() {
    var roll = $('#roll').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'test2.php',
      data: 'roll_id=' + roll,
      success: function(value) {
        var data = value.split(",");
        $('#attend').val(data[0]);
        $('#conduct').val(data[1]);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Add your `data` response in your question.

Comment: i didnt get you

Comment: We need to see what's held in the `data` variable, ie. the result of `value.split(",")`

Comment: `var data = value.split(",");` response Add by `console.log(data)` in your question.

Comment: what do you have inside this file `test2.php`?

Comment: You have callback `success: function(value)` - what's in the `value`? I think you have some extra spaces there.

Comment: Please check my answer guys, i was able to reproduce the same and it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert it to an integer. you are using `type="number"` so it may cause that issue.

```
 var attend = parseInt(data[0]);
 $('#attend').val(attend);
```

for a better way, you should split your variables from the PHP file.

then use `parseJson` to get the seperate values.

Comment: No this is the answer, please check your code again. I have updated there, i also tried the split method there, it not showing for number boxes. but now it is showing

Comment: This solves the problem, but I still recommend to fix response also.

Comment: This only solves the problem because the AJAX response isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: Yes! you are crct.